# Loading the C runtime on Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, assembly, dll

Being a newbie on Linux I have some questions:
How do I load the C runtime from a program?
What's the path and file name?

On windows it's

```
C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
```

By the way, what are DLLs called on Linux?

What are the functions corresponding to MS `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`?
In what DLL do they reside?
Which library must I link to get access to them?
Under Windows it's `kernel32.lib` and `kernel32.dll`.

Finally: How do I write Masm/JWasm code independent of the target platform?
Is there an assembler symbol reflecting the target arg used on the command line?

Edit: A couple of more questions I forgot to ask: Is Linux 64 bit or 32 bit? Does it use the same calling convention as 64 bit MS C? I mean the parameters in rcx, rdx, r8, r9 and so on.

Comment: You can use `dlopen()` to load a new dynamically-linked library.

Comment: You cannot write assembler code independent of the target platform.

Comment: A lot of questions, most inappropriate for stack oveflow. Do some research, read some books, learn the basics. There is enough information to be found by simple serach for all topics.

Comment: If you want to use C runtime library functions on Windows or Linux you don't need to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress or the equivalent Linux functions.

Comment: To your edit: Linux is available for a variety of architectures and of course for both i386 and amd64. On i386, Linux uses a calling convention very similar to cdecl, on amd64 the SysV ABI for amd64 is used which passes argument in `rdi`, `rsi`, `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8`, and `r9` as well as `xmm0` to `xmm7`. The convention is slightly complicated for structures passed by value.

Comment: If you want to create platform-dependent, non-portable programs, by all means choose Assembly language. Otherwise settle for C language.

Answer (score 8):

Typical UNIX-like systems use the ELF file format for object files, shared libraries and binaries. Many things are similar to Windows but some are different. First, here is a list of commonly used suffixes:

```
UNIX    Windows
*.o     *.obj   object file 
*.a     *.lib   static library
*.so    *.dll   shared object (ELF targets)
*.dylib *.dll   shared object (Mach O targets, i.e. Mac OS X)
*       *.exe   binary (no suffix on UNIX)
```

Static linking works mostly the same way as on Windows, but dynamic linking is different. First of all, shared libraries do not have lib files. Instead, the static linker `ld` generates an appropriate PLT (procedure linkage table) with stubs for each function you call when you want to call into a shared object directly. In this usage scenario, what shared objects you link to is stored in a special section in your binary. Your binary is not directly executed, instead the dynamic loader `ld.so` is loaded as an interpreter for your binary, finds all needed shared objects and loads them into the address space. Symbol references are resolved on first call (unless you specify otherwise).

You can also load shared objects at runtime using the `dl` library which provides the functions `dlopen`, `dlclose`, `dlsym`, and `dlerror` to load shared objects and access symbols in them. Note that the `dl` library likely depends on parts of the libc being available as all system calls are done through the libc. On some UNIX-like operating systems, the libdl is integrated into the libc.

You can of course also manually load shared objects but doing so is complicated.

There is no direct equivalent to Microsoft's `kernel32.dll`. System calls are implemented in the C standard library `libc.so` (which is also available statically as `libc.a`) but you can also call the operating system directly. The stability of the assembly system call interface varies between operating systems but the libc interface is stable. I highly recommend you to exclusively call into the operating system using the libc.

The CRT comprises the libc and a couple of object files that are linked into your program when you link through the C compiler. These object files retrieve the argument vector and ELF auxillary vector from the stack and call into the libc. The libc then calls `main` for you. I highly recommend you to always link through the C compiler and to have your assembly program start at `main`. This allows for much easier and portable programming.

For further reading, I recommend you to read the [SysV ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) and the documentation on the ELF format.

If you want to use the libc, I recommend you to link through the C compiler:

```
cc -o binary object1.o object2.o ... -llibrary1 -llibrary2 ...
```

This also links the CRT entry stub into your program; you program itself should provide a global symbol named `main` which is called by the libc in the ABI's calling convention (on i386, cdecl is used for all functions, on amd64 the SysV ABI calling convention is used). The signature is as follows:

```
main(argc, argv, envp);
```

where `argc` is the number of command line arguments, argv is a pointer to a null-terminated array of pointers to the command line arguments and envp is a pointer to a null-terminated array of environment variables (each entry has the form `key=value`. If `main` returns, the C runtime invokes the `exit` function with the return value of `main` as the exit status. Note that `exit` flushes all stdio buffers so you don't have to do that.

You can also create a static binary using the `-static` option:

```
cc -static -o binary object1.o object2.o ... -llibrary1 -llibrary2 ...
```

Note that some libc functionality (e.g. DNS lookups) require the dynamic loading of shared libraries, if you use any of these functions shared libraries might be opened during the execution of your program.

If you do not want to use the libc, you link your program with `ld`, the linker:

```
ld -o binary object1.o ... -llibrary1 ...
```

in this case, the entry point to your program is a global symbol named `_start`, the operating system places a bunch of useful things on the stack on startup, read the aforementioned ABI document for details.

`stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are available as file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 respectively. It is not guaranteed that they are open. You can use the standard POSIX functions `read()` and `write()` to read and write data to and from them. Accessing the pointers to the C `FILE` structures `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` depends on the operating system you program for. On Linux these are just external symbols but on other systems (e.g. FreeBSD) you might need to call a function to get the pointers.

Comment: A very informative answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How exactly do you propose that I link my assembly program? Link with libc.so and dl.so? Will contol pass through libc then just like in a C program? How will the command line args and stdin/stdout be made available to me? I have to use all the C include files then just like in a C program? I get the feeling that Linux isn't suitable for asm programming.

Comment: @Henrik See my updated answer. Assembly programming on Linux is possible though I recommend to implement the parts that interact with the operating system in C as that's simpler to get right.

Comment: @Henrik Generally, almost all programs link in the libc. The POSIX standard specifies the libc and no interface below that so linking against the libc is the most portable way to write software (including assembly programs). There are some languages whose compilers don't, notably Go.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I load the C runtime from a program?

Normally the C runtime is loaded into the program image long before `main` is called. In fact *it is* the runtime that is doing the `main`-calling. BTW, it's just like that in Windows, too; with the slight speciality that Windows programs can have a `WinMain` instead of `main`.

However if your intention is locating the symbol addresses inside the C runtime then you can `dlopen` in lieu of `GetModuleHandle` or `LoadLibrary`.

> On windows it's `C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll`

Actually it's `%SYSPATH%\msvcrt.dll`, but nitpicking aside…

On *nix-systems it's (usually) `/lib/libc.so`

> By the way, what are DLLs called on Linux?

Shared Objects. Hence the file suffix `.so` – or rather `.so.$VERSION`, e.g. `libsomething.so.1.2`

Mandatory reading regarding shared objects: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf

> What are the functions corresponding to MS LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress?

`dlopen` and `dlsym`

> In what DLL do they reside?

They're located in `libdl.so`

> Which library must I link to get access to them?

`libdl.so`

Comment: You're assuming that I'm programming in C, but I'm not. Assembly, man! No C library is loaded automatically. Of course, I can accomplish that by linking the lib glue to the C runtime, but I want to avoid that. I want my prog to decide when to load the CRT if at all. Otherwise thanks for the generous answer.

Comment: MSVCRT is not the MSVC runtime library! See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273

Comment: @GovindParmar: Yes and no. `%SYSPATH%\msvcrt.dll` is the runtime library to be used for writing drivers and similar system level stuff, *but not for binaries compiled with recent versions of MSVC++*. It's *also* the runtime library of MSVC++ 6 and before (as explained in the article you linked).

Answer (score 1):

I found these nice solutions, none of my own inventions:

```
;--- "hello world" for Linux which uses int 80h.
;--- assemble: jwasm -Fo=Linux1.o Linux1.asm
;--- link:     jwlink format ELF runtime linux file Linux1.o name Linux1

    .386
    .model flat

stdout    equ 1
SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_WRITE equ 4

    .data

string  db 10,"Hello, world!",10

    .code

_start:

    mov ecx, offset string
    mov edx, sizeof string
    mov ebx, stdout
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    int 80h
    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    int 80h

    end _start
```

Ah that's ever so nice. And this one:

```
;--- "hello world" for 64-bit Linux, using SYSCALL.
;--- assemble: JWasm -elf64 -Fo=Lin64_1.o Lin64_1.asm
;--- link:     gcc Lin64_1.o -o Lin64_1

stdout    equ 1
SYS_WRITE equ 1
SYS_EXIT  equ 60

    .data

string  db 10,"Hello, world!",10

    .code

_start:
    mov edx, sizeof string
    mov rsi, offset string
    mov edi, stdout
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    syscall
    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    syscall

    end _start
```

Brilliant! That was what I was looking for. Low level stuff. The first is just like good old MSDOS with int 80h interface to the Linux system. The other one uses the syscall instruction.

And it's so simple! There's nothing like it in windows. Seems that asm progr is much easier under Linux than win after all. This raises a few questions, though:

Is the syscall instr only available under 64 bit Linux?

Are the system routines available through syscall / int 80h well documented? Are they abundant? Can you do without clib.so?

The contributions by others above, while valuable, are clearly the work of C programmers. I'm more akin to Linux bit hackers working in asm.

In particular, is there a system call for loading an SO and inquiring about function adresses?

Comment: On i386 Linux, all system calls are done through int 80h, they are stable and somewhat documented (search the internet). For all but a few system calls, a corresponding function is available in the libc. Same thing for amd64 but system calls are done with the syscall instruction and the numbers are different.

Comment: The kernel knows nothing about shared libraries, all loading of shared libraries is done by userland code in `libdl.so` and `ld.so` (which searches for libraries, maps them into the address space and resolves functions). Unless you write your own code to do that, there is no way to get that functionality without linking in these libraries.

Comment: Lastly, answers are not for follow up questions. If you have further questions, make a new question or try to answer them some other way.

Comment: @fuz: Thanks a lot for good info. I begin to understand.

Comment: @fuz: Is the asm source of the C functions in libc.so available? If so I could include the ones I need in my asm source instead of bothering with SOs. When I run a prog in a Linux shell (say bash) who is doing the loading and relocating and running? Is that LD too? The kernel knows nothing about that either?

Comment: The entire libc  is written in C except for a very small part (e.g. setting up the FPU configuration). There is no asm source but the libc can be found e.g. [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/).

Comment: If you don't want to bother with shared objects, then link in the libc statically. This pulls only the parts your program absolutely needs. To your last question, there is a dynamic loader `ld.so` which is contrary to its name not a shared object. An ELF binary can have an interpreter section which tells the operating system to load an interpreter for the binary. This feature is used to load `ld.so` as an interpreter, `ld.so` then proceeds to load the shared libraries for your binary and stays around for fixing up relocations.

Comment: @fuz As for static linking with libc: I'm crosslinking for Linux with JWlink on windows. JWlink understands ELF but not SO.  Is the static lib ELF? If so then I can download it and link it to my asm prog on win. Otherwise I'll have to compile the C source on Linux and download the object files.

Comment: @fuz Is it possible to load and run the services of ld.so from a program? I just loved the old days of MSDOS where everything you could do on the command line also had a system call version so that you could do it from a (asm) program too. I wish Linux were the same, that every extension to the kernel were registered with the kernel and got a function number to use when syscalling. In this way a prog could use the same syscall interface for all external services, whatever their nature.

Comment: It is possible, using the libdl. I highly recommend you to use a proper toolchain for Linux development. On UNIX-like systems, static libraries are `ar` archives containing a bunch of object files; shared objects are different and similar to binaries. Please get rid of the idea that you can make Linux by like DOS. On Linux, the OS interface is exposed through the libc. You should really use that, if you don't you are in for a hard time. And no, dynamic linking is not a kernel extension. The kernel knows nothing about it.

Comment: Note that so files are also in the ELF object file format. All binaries, core dumps, object files, and shared objects are.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the functions corresponding to MS LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress?

`dlopen` and `dlsym`, respectively.

> In what DLL do they reside?

Usually, `libdl`. Use `-ldl` in linker command line to attach it.